# What is wrong with this syntax for my elif statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am the most beginner of the beginners and I'm getting a syntax error message for the semicolon after 'elif' why is that? Also, should the code work otherwise?

```
#a - this program uses function valid(x) to determine if the user's input is a positive, non-zero number while imposing a limit of 3 attempts

def valid(x):
    return (x > 0)
n = int(input('Please input a positive non-zero number: '))
if(valid(n)== True):
    print(n,'is valid')
elif:
    print(u = int(input('error please input a positive non-zero number: ')))
    if(valid(u)== True):
        print(u,'is valid')
elif:
    print(m = int(input('error please input a positive non-zero number: ')))
    if(valid(m)== True):
            print(m,'is valid')
```

Comment: `elif` also needs a condition; you're thinking of `else`.

Comment: Well... `elif ` *what*, exactly?!

Comment: @Evert but there can't be two `else`s, either.

Comment: With `elif` you have to mention a condition like `valid(n)== False`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know; but I'm guessing the second `elif` should be indented.

Comment: Error aside, you probably want to use a `while` loop to repeat the same retry code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a proper syntax for if..else condition in python. Are you following this?

```
if expression1:
   statement(s)
elif expression2:
   statement(s)
elif expression3:
   statement(s)
else:
   statement(s)
```

The **elif** statement allows you to check multiple expressions for TRUE and execute a block of code as soon as one of the conditions evaluates to TRUE. In your code snippet, there is no expression to be executed in the **elif** statement!

I believe you need something like as follows.

```
# This program uses function valid(x) to determine if the user's input is positive, non-zero number while imposing a limit of 3 attempts
def valid(x):
    return (x > 0)

n = int(input('Please input a positive non-zero number: '))
if(valid(n)== True):
    print(n,'is valid')
else:
    n = int(input('error please input a positive non-zero number: '))
    if(valid(n)== True):
        print(n,'is valid')
    else:
        n = int(input('error please input a positive non-zero number: '))
        if(valid(n)== True):
            print(n,'is valid')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid because `elif` is short for `else if` and you don't have a condition to test. Try just using `else:` for that.

Also, don't compare against `True`. Just let the expression stand alone. And this isn't C or Java, so no parens around conditionals:

```
if(valid(n)== True):
    print(n,'is valid')
```

Becomes:

```
if valid(n):
    print(n, 'is valid')
```

Comment: You can't use `else:` more than once.

Comment: I think that's just bad formatting of the question. There's an indented `if` in there.

Comment: That could be; I hadn't thought of that.  In case it isn't, though, I would suggest making that clear in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just offering a more concise solution (and pythonic). `elif`s need a condition. You can use a `for` loop to check the password three times. And if the password is correct, the loop ends.

```
def valid(x):
    return x > 0

for i in range(3):
    n = input('Please input a positive non-zero number: ')
    if valid(n):
        print(n, 'is valid')
        break
```